# Is it possible to change an XML config file using Pax Exam?

Tags: xml, junit, osgi, fuseesb, pax-exam

I want to run multiple Fuse instances using Pax Exam on the same machine, and I want to reconfigure all used ports to make this possible. Unfortunately one port is defined in the etc/jetty.xml. Is there a way to have it changed somehow? I see that there is a set of options called `KarafDistributionOption.editConfigurationFile*` but they work only with property files.

- Is there any Option implementation to use?
- Is there any event hook like "here is the fuse installation, do what you want before I start that" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Got it:

```
KarafDistributionOption.replaceConfigurationFile(configurationFilePath, source)
```

So what I do is:

- I save the original XML into my unit test jar as resource
- in the configuration phase I change the port
- with the Option above I replace the config file in the target Fuse.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Completed the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that the File source can be from the local project.  `KarafDistributionOption.replaceConfigurationFile("etc/my.props.cfg", new File("src/test/resources/my.props.cfg"));`